# How to get the mail body beyond 255 characters?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am retrieving emails through the following code but I am only getting 255 characters instead of the whole body.

Is there any way to remove this limit?

```
const api = client
  .api("/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages")
  .top(10)
  .select("subject,from,receivedDateTime,isRead,bodyPreview")
  .orderby("receivedDateTime DESC")
  .get((err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("getMessages returned an error: " + err.message);
    } else {
      console.log("Mails are retrieving...");

      res.value.forEach(function(message) {
        console.log(message.bodyPreview);
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muthurathinam is correct, but for the sake of clarity and future uses, I'm adding a more in-depth answer.

Your code is currently requesting only the following properties:

- `subject`
- `from`
- `receivedDateTime`
- `isRead`
- `bodyPreview`

The reason why you're only recieving 255 characters of the message is because you're requesting `bodyPreview`. Looking at the documentation, `bodyPreview` is defined as follows:

> `bodyPreview` - `String` - The first 255 characters of the message body. It is in text format.

What you're actually looking for is the `body` property. The `body` property returns a [`itemBody`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/itembody) object that contains two properties:

- `content` - The content of the item.
- `contentType` - The type of the content. Possible values are `Text` and `HTML`.

This means that instead of `console.log(message.bodyPreview)` you will need to use `console.log(message.body.content)`.

Here is your sample code, refactored to use `body`:

```
const api = client
  .api("/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages")
  .top(10)
  .select("subject,from,receivedDateTime,isRead,body")
  .orderby("receivedDateTime DESC")
  .get((err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("getMessages returned an error: " + err.message);
    } else {
      console.log("Mails are retrieving...");

      res.value.forEach(function(message) {
        console.log(message.body.content);
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for mail body. So, try selecting `body` instead of `bodyPreview`.

Here is the graph [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_messages#example) example which has the body in its response.